# how can i access folder outside wwroot?

Tags: asp.net, iis, relative-path

my website support to view and edit a lot of documents that contains a lot of images a huge number 
images folder size equal 500 giga
when i developed my website i created image folder in my website to access images
but when published my website the customer need a page to specify any folder path of image folder, cause it's to hard for him to copy all images, and size of partition c is another problem . so he has these images in external hard and want to set in setting page path of image folder and then my website look at this path (on server )
how can i access these images on external hard

Answer (score 2):

Make a virtual directory inside your website and give path of folder that is outside your website folder that has images. Now this folder will act as it is part of your website and you will be able to give virtual path. How to create Virtual Directory see this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link

Suppose you have website folder d:\Yoursites\Testsite and you want to access files within d:\Images\first\file\a.jpgpdf, make a virtual directory in side TestWebsite pointing to d:\images \files and access files within it through virual directory.

The URL for images pdf would be something like 
http://yoursite.com/yourvirtualdirectoryname/first.jpg

Comment: thanks can i make virtual directory from my asp.net website i means in code cause customer my change harddisk

Comment: You can use installer project to configure the virtual directory path, check this out, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5821/All-about-Installers-Customizing-Windows-and-Web-s